# I need to highlight games by their classification rating XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to get my games highlighted by color according to their classification. I've searched around and have been unable to make anything work so far. My latest efforts involved trying to use.

```
<xsl:if test="substring(rating, string-length(rating) -3) = M">
 <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color: red</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```

The information needs to be displayed in a table (got that covered) and then Highlighted by rating classifications. At this stage I am just trying to get "M" rated games highlighted in red.

Here is my XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="styles.xsl"?>

    <Games>
    <game>
        <title>Aliens Colonial Marines</title>
        <platform>Xbox 360</platform>
        <dev>Gearbox Software</dev>
        <pub>Sega</pub>
        <composer>Kevin Riepl</composer>
        <release>Feburary 12, 2013</release>
        <rating>MA 15+</rating>
        <engine>Red Ring</engine>
        <game_mode>Single-Player, Multiplayer</game_mode>
    </game>
    <game>
        <title>Assasins Creed IV Black Flag </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>:Ubisoft Montreal  </dev>
        <pub>Ubisoft  </pub>
        <composer>Brian Tyler  </composer>
        <release>October 29, 2013  </release>
        <rating>MA 15+  </rating>
        <engine>AnvilNext </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Multiplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game>
        <title>Defiance  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Trion Worlds, Human Head Studios  </dev>
        <pub>Trion Worlds  </pub>
        <composer>Unnamed  </composer>
        <release>April 2, 2013  </release>
        <rating>MA 15+  </rating>
        <engine>Unnamed  </engine>
        <game_mode>Multiplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Grand Theft Auto V  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Rockstar North  </dev>
        <pub>Rockstar Games  </pub>
        <composer> Tangerine Dream, Woody Jackson, The Alchemist, Oh No      </composer>
        <release>September 17, 2013 </release>
        <rating>R 18+  </rating>
        <engine>RAGE with Euphoria and Bullet Physics  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Online Multiplayer </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game>
        <title>Halo 3 ODST  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Bungie  </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Game Studios </pub>
        <composer>Martin O'Donnell, Micheal Salvatori  </composer>
        <release>September 22, 2009 </release>
        <rating>M  </rating>
        <engine>Halo Engine </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Co-Op, Multiplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game>
        <title>Halo 3  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Bungie  </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Game Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Martin O'Donnell  </composer>
        <release>September 25, 2007 </release>
        <rating>M  </rating>
        <engine>Halo Engine  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single Player, Multiplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Halo 4 </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>343 Industries  </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Studios </pub>
        <composer>Neil Davidge </composer>
        <release>November 6, 2012  </release>
        <rating>M  </rating>
        <engine>Halo Engine  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Multiplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
        <game> 
        <title>Halo Anniversary  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>343 Industries </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Martin O'Donnell, Michael Salvatori  </composer>
        <release>November 15, 2011  </release>
        <rating>MA 15+ </rating>
        <engine>Saber3D Engine v.S3 </engine>
        <game_mode>ingle-player, Multiplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Halo Reach  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Bungie </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Martin O'Donnell, Michael Salvatori </composer>
        <release>September 14, 2010  </release>
        <rating>MA 15+  </rating>
        <engine>Halo Engine  </engine>
        <game_mode>ingle Player, Co-Op, Mulitplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Halo Spartan Assault  </title>
        <platform>Xbox One </platform>
        <dev>343 Industries, Vanguard Entertainment  </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Game Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Tom Salta </composer>
        <release>December 24, 2013  </release>
        <rating>M </rating>
        <engine>Unnamed  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Co-Op  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Halo Wars </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Ensemble Studios  </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Game Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Stephen Rippy   </composer>
        <release>Feburary 26, 2009 </release>
        <rating>PG  </rating>
        <engine>BANG! Engine  </engine>
        <game_mode>Signle-player  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Kinect Adventures  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Good Science Studio  </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Games Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Unnamed  </composer>
        <release>November 4, 2010  </release>
        <rating>PG  </rating>
        <engine>Unreal 3 Engine  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Multiplayer </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Kinectimals  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Frontier Developments  </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Game Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Unnamed  </composer>
        <release>November 4,2010 </release>
        <rating>G  </rating>
        <engine>Unnamed  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Lightning Returns: Final Fantasy XIII  </title>
        <platform> Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Square Enix  </dev>
        <pub>Square Enix  </pub>
        <composer>Masashi Hamauzu, Naoshi Mizuta  </composer>
        <release>Feburary 11, 2014  </release>
        <rating>M</rating>
        <engine>Crystal Tools  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Mass Effect 2  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>BioWare  </dev>
        <pub>Electronic Arts  </pub>
        <composer>Jack Wall  </composer>
        <release>January 26, 2010  </release>
        <rating>MA 15+  </rating>
        <engine>Unreal Engine 3  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Mass Effect  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>BioWare   </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Game Studios   </pub>
        <composer>Jack Wall, Sam Hulick, Richard Jacques  </composer>
        <release>November 16, 2007  </release>
        <rating>MA 15+  </rating>
        <engine>Unreal Engine 3 </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Rocksmith  </title>
        <platform> box 360 </platform>
        <dev>Ubisoft San Francisco  </dev>
        <pub>Ubisoft  </pub>
        <composer>Multiple (Bands) </composer>
        <release>October 18, 2011  </release>
        <rating>PG  </rating>
        <engine>Unnamed  </engine>
        <game_mode>Unnamed  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Ryse, Son of Rome </title>
        <platform>Xbox One </platform>
        <dev>Crytek Frankfurt  </dev>
        <pub>Microsoft Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Bosiclav Slavov, Tilman Sillescu </composer>
        <release>November 22, 2013 </release>
        <rating>R 18+ </rating>
        <engine>CryEngine </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Multiplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Titanfall  </title>
        <platform>Xbox One </platform>
        <dev>Respawn Entertainment  </dev>
        <pub>Electronic Arts  </pub>
        <composer>Stepehn Barton </composer>
        <release>March 11, 2014  </release>
        <rating>MA 15+ </rating>
        <engine>Source  </engine>
        <game_mode>Online Multiplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Tomb Raider  </title>
        <platform>Xbox One </platform>
        <dev>Crystal Dyanmics </dev>
        <pub>Square Enix  </pub>
        <composer>Jason Graves  </composer>
        <release>March 5, 2013  </release>
        <rating>MA 15+  </rating>
        <engine>Modified Crystal Engine  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Mulitplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Too Human  </title>
        <platform>Xbox 360 </platform>
        <dev>Silicon Knights  </dev>
        <pub>Micosoft Game Studios  </pub>
        <composer>Steve Henifin  </composer>
        <release>August 19, 2008 </release>
        <rating>M </rating>
        <engine>Unreal Engine 3 Havok Physics  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player, Mulitplayer  </game_mode>
    </game>
    <game> 
        <title>Wolfenstein The New Order  </title>
        <platform>Xbox One </platform>
        <dev>MachineGames </dev>
        <pub>Bethesda Softwork  </pub>
        <composer>Mick Gordon  </composer>
        <release>May 20, 2014  </release>
        <rating>R 18+  </rating>
        <engine>id Tech 5  </engine>
        <game_mode>Single-player  </game_mode>
    </game>
</Games>
```

And here is my XSL thus far

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
        <h2>Xbox Games Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Platform</th>
                <th>Developer</th>
                <th>Publisher</th>
                <th>Composer</th>
                <th>Rlease</th>
                <th>Rating</th>
                <th>Engine</th>
                <th>Game Mode</th>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="Games/game">
                <tr>
                    <xsl:if test="substring(rating, string-length(rating) -3) = M">
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color: red</xsl:attribute>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="platform"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="dev"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="pub"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="composer"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="release"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="rating"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="engine"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="game_mode"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If any one could give me some direction on how to do it for one, I can add the others in myself.

Thanks in advance

Vriss

Comment: Can you explain in simple language which games are supposed to be highlighted?

Comment: just a guess - I think that removing the last 3 chars could be the problem. Don' t you need to get the first 3 chars, remove whitespace and then compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem with your code is that it refers to a non-exisitng element named `M` instead of to a string `"M"`.

Assuming that otherwise the logic reflects what you want (does it?), you just need to change:

```
<xsl:if test="substring(rating, string-length(rating) -3) = M">
```

to:

```
<xsl:if test="substring(rating, string-length(rating) -3) = 'M'">
```

---

> At this stage I am just trying to get "M" rated games highlighted in
>   red.

If I had to guess, I would say that "M" rated games are those that pass this test:

```
<xsl:if test="normalize-space(rating) = 'M'">
```

At least that highlights the games that **display** `M` in the `Rating` column.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. <xsl:if test="normalize-space(rating) = 'M'"> provides the solution I require.